# Set the transport of the Customizer 'header_image' core setting to 'postMessage'

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, customization, themes

To activate the Customizer core section Navigation *(ID: nav)*, you need to:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );
```

I already tried to make the transport of the Customizer `header_image` setting `postMessage` with the ID based on what I'm seeing at [get_header_image()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L1057):

```
function theme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->get_setting( 'header_image' )->transport = 'postMessage';

    // I also tried this line.
    // $wp_customize->get_setting( 'header_image', get_theme_support( 'custom-header', 'default-image' ) )->transport = 'postMessage';
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'theme_customize_register' );
```

But the setting transport is still `refresh`. And because the code above didn't work, it looks like the ID of the Customizer **Header Image** setting is not `header_image`.. What is the Header Image's ID and how to make it `postMessage`?

Answer (score 3):

Luckily, I was facing the same issue an hour ago so I brainstormed for a long time to find a find a solution. I posted it here before seeing this: http://www.hardeepasrani.com/2015/12/using-postmessage-transport-method-for-header-image/

So instead of just using:

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'header_image' )->transport = 'postMessage';
```

I used:

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'header_image'  )->transport = 'postMessage';
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'header_image_data'  )->transport = 'postMessage';
```

After that, in JS, we got the value using header_image.

Hope it helps you. :)

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution, but please extend your link-only answer. The link could change in the future, thus making the answer not useful to others. Thanks.

Comment: @birgire Done. :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I am glad I found this before jumping into the source.